# an elegant way to handle returning strpos 0 as TRUE

Tags: php, coding-style, strpos, boolean-operations

```
switch (true){
    case stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"mydomain.com", 0) :

        //do something 
        break;

        /*
        stripos returns 4 ( which in turn evaluates as TRUE )  
        when the current URL is www.mydomain.com
        */


    default:

        /*
        stripos returns 0 ( which in turn evaluates as FALSE )  
        when the current URL is mydomain.com
        */


}
```

when stripos finds the needle in the haystack returns 0 or up. 
when stripos does not find the needle, it returns FALSE. There could be some advatages of this approach. But I don't like that!

I'm coming from VB background. There, instr function (which is the equivalent of strpos) returns 0 when it cannot find the needle and returns 1 or up if it finds it.

so the above code never causes a problem.

how do you elegantly handle this situation in PHP?  What's the best practice approach here?

Also, on a different note, what do you think about using the

```
switch(true)
```

Is that a good way to write code to begin with?

Comment: what's wrong with if(stripos(....) === false){ ...} else { ... }

Comment: nothing wrong. so you are suggesting to code it as case (stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"mydomain.com", 0) === TRUE)    Is that the most elegant way?

Comment: I'd use an if statement. What's the point of using switch()? I'm far from a php expert though!

Comment: Your `switch` doesn't work. And if you want to eschew the `===false` boolean hump, then use `strstr()` and let PHPs string evaluation handle it.

Comment: What's wrong with the switch? syntax error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strpos returns false if the needle doesn't exist within the haystack.  By default (using non-strict comparison), PHP will treat 0 and false as equivilant.  You need to use strict comparison.

```
var_dump (strpos ('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'dog') !== false); // bool (true)
var_dump (strpos ('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'The') !== false); // bool (true)
var_dump (strpos ('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'cat') !== false); // bool (false)
```

Comment: I'll take that answer. ( though I don't think it's elegantly reading ). I guess there is nothing we can do about it. It's just the way strpos and PHP is wired. if (strpos("abc","a") ) returning true would be the most elegant way from the get go. But that's not gonna ever happen. In this case, "strstr" like mario suggested makes more sense.  I ticked his comment up.

Comment: I don't agree that strpos ('abc', 'a') should return true.  The strpos function, as its name implies, returns the position of the haystack within the needle.  If the haystack happens to have the needle at the start then it's perfectly valid to return a position of 0 (strings are comparable to 0-indexed arrays in this context).

Comment: Well, whether you/I like/hate it, that's not gonna change. As to your comment, it would have been better if the strpos sucker returned 1 when it finds the "a" at the beginning "abc". It's all part of the same stupidity that arrays must start from 0. Jan 0 and December 11. that 0 based thing works only in elevators in real life. Ground floor is treated as 0. Even that is stupid!

Comment: Here is a nice reading on this; http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm

Comment: @AverageJoe almost every programming language uses 0-indexing for strings and arrays, due to reasons tied to the underlying architecture of computers. (If you had a computer with an 8 bit address space then it would have 256 memory addresses.  But if you started at 1 for the first address, then the last address would be 256, which requires 9 bits to represent. If you start at 0 then the last address is 255, which can be represented with 8 bits)

Comment: I know I know Gordon. I've been around. I just wanted to unload my anger to the original design principle. Human mind gets into all kinds of interpretetions when dealing with concepts such as infinity, 0, empty, null, nothing, blank, etc.

Comment: Never bothered me.  I guess I've just been doing it so long that I don't really notice anymore until someone actually brings it up.  I tend to think of it as the number representing the number of things that come before the one being addressed.  Nothing comes before the first character, so 0.

Comment: why are you so angry average joe? are u really proposing that `strpos` ( "get me the position aka INDEX of a string" ) should return true ? really? aren't u confusing this with `str_contains` somehow? i kind of wanna go ahead and state that you blame the architecture for your own incompetence. but i guess i'm chasing ghosts from 2012 here. it was a different time, hating online was still accepted